# ffmpeg - very slow conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I create web app in JavaEE which displays many video formats. I use ffmpeg solution to convert videos to formats which is supported natively by main browsers.

According to : http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/formats/ 
I convert to WEBM container (VP8/VORBIS or VP9/OPUS). But conversion is very slow, bit rate equals to ~ 200kbits/s. To convert I execute following command

`ffmpeg -i file.mov -c:v libvpx -preset ultrafast result.webm`

How to speed up conversion to natively supported formats by main browsers?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? If yes; please share it here, I also have the same problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Use the `-speed` number (e.g. 8), not the `-preset` setting (e.g. `ultrafast`). The latter is for `x264/x265` encoding.

*A Higher number means faster encoding*, so `ultrafast` would map to 8 or so. `Very slow/placebo` maps to 0, and values in between map accordingly. 1-2 still gives reasonably good results and settings like 4-5 tend to be relatively fast **but not** entirely crap quality.

Comment: I set `speed` argument to `16` but it is still to slow for me, ffmpeg 13MB `mov` file converts to 7b `webm` file within 30 seconds. Are there any other arguments to speed up conversion? Probably ffmpeg server can help me with stream file 'Live'?

Comment: Try -deadline realtime -cpu-used -16 (-cpu-used is the same as -speed), that's a realtime setting, the quality will definitely suffer but it'll be significantly faster. Also make sure you're running a recent libvpx+ffmpeg version.

Comment: Ok, I used it before. Thank you ;)

Comment: I didn't see `-speed` or `-cpu-used` in man manual of ffmpeg ...  , and wondering what's the default cpu count to use, if not specified.

Comment: In my test, `-preset ultrafast` makes it faster, and `-speed 8` doesn't make any change.